# How can i change the size of a HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html

how can i change the size of an html canvas through a function? i tried `Width=123;"`
 and `canvas.style.Width=123 canvas.width=123` neither of them worked heres the HTML code for the canvas `<CANVAS id="canvas" width="460px" height="800px"></CANVAS>` and in the css `canvasarea { width: 460px; height: 800px;`

Comment: Have in mind that if you already placed content into the canvas, it will be stretched when resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<canvas>` element supports the `width` attribute.

example: `<canvas width="123"></canvas>`

to change the width with javascript do something like:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<script type="javascript">

function changeCanvasWidth() {
    myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    myCanvas.style.width="123px";
}
</script>
```

reference: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_canvas.asp